# Extract time from a date time string in excel

Tags: excel

i have this string which is in a date and time format (10/25/2013  8:54:00 PM),i want to extract the time from each cell and sum them to find the total time.

please can someone suggest me how to do it???

Comment: Sum time? seems odd.. can you provide some sample data and expected results?

Comment: actually i have to prepare a report on how much time does it take to open a case and close a case in fogbugz,i have imported the data in excel to calculate it


10/25/2013 20:54
10/24/2013 10:14
10/28/2013 15:20
10/25/2013 20:54
10/24/2013 10:16
10/24/2013 10:14

Comment: So you need to get the DIFFERENCE in two times taking into acocunt the date (not all cases are open and closed on the same day are they?) shouldn't you subtract the end time from the start time and then convert that to hour/mm if needed?

Comment: can i have the formula??

Comment: Let me rephrase: What is the expected output?  DD:HH:MM:SS?  where DD is days open HH is hours MM minutes and SS second?  Or would just a 1.33 or 1.99 be ok where 1 is days and .33 is 1/3 of a day or 99 is 99/100 of a day... without knowing desired end result, I can't say what a formula would be.  pnuts answer seems to be the closest so far but, sample data and expected results in initial question (Edit it) would help me the most.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this formula to extract the time:

```
=TIME(HOUR(A1),MINUTE(A1),SECOND(A1))
```

Then, summarize the values and use "d h:mm" number format for the cell.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your date format is `MM\DD\YYYY h:mm:ss AM/PM`. Use this formula to extract time value:

```
=TIMEVALUE(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-11))
```

This value is in days. I.e. if there is 6 hours, the value will be 0.25. To get number of hours multiply it by 24.

Comment: Doesn't this only apply if the string is a text string? From what the OP says, it seems as if the string is a recognised Excel Date/Time format.

Comment: Yes, the source must be text string, not Excel value.

Answer (score 0):

If your string is a properly-recognised Excel Date/Time format, simply:

=MOD(A1,1)

Format as hh:mm if you wish.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

If you values are in ColumnA (start) and B (corresponding finish) then something like:

```
=B1-A1
```

formatted as Time should suit with summing of the results.